# Solr indexing  increasing speed?

Tags: solr, solrj, pdfbox

I'm trying to figure out whats holding the index speed back.
I'm extracting text from pdf's to index each page seperatly to solr to get page hit results.

I was using commit after every "document". Then I noticed its spend loads of time rebuilding the index euch time I used commit.

Now I use this:

```
      <autoCommit> <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs> <maxTime>60000</maxTime> </autoCommit>
```

To get a commit every minute.

But then I was calculating and found out it indexed around **30 'documents'(pages as solrDoc)/sec or 10 real documents/sec**. This seems pretty slow compared to other setups.

**How could I increase my speed?**

Extra info:(request if needed)

- My documents contain 7 fields.(1 content field with the text on the page)
- I use *Solrj* to add documents to solr.
- I'm using the *example config* since I have no advanced knowledge of Solr
- pc intel core i7 2600+16Gb ram+ssd (this is a dev computer not the
  final server but it     should be pretty fast) *Not much of the cpu and ram is used.*
- I get the files from an *external storage*. (but its fast I could easily get 12MB/s)
- I extract the text using *pdfbox*
- It took *390 Minutes* to make a *650Mb index(455600 solrdocuments )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one aspect is whether your process is multithreaded or not, if not, test by having several threads extracting text from pdf and then hand over to solr for indexing.

Comment: It worked now I've created 4 threads that read pdf's. And it goes alot faster. I'll experiment with threads to optimize my pdf indexing speed.